# Why can't admins view user's redirected folders?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, folder-redirection

Followed this doc to setup folder redirection: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078(v=ws.11).aspx

Setup permissions like so:
[image]

But in addition to a "Folder Redirection Users" group I created a "Folder Redirection Admins" group and gave that group "This folder, subfolders and files = full control" (same as systems's perms).

So now as a member of my admins group I can transverse the top level of user's folders, but didn't have access to their subfolders (like desktop, documents, etc).

So the user's top level folders, when they get created, are inheriting my admins group, but the folder under them are not.

Why not and how do I get my admins group added to these folders when they get created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a specific setting in the Folder Redirection GPO setting that you need to disable, regardless of NTFS permissions on the parent folder, in order to allow access to the child folder. You need to uncheck the "Grant the user exclusive rights to Documents" checkbox. Note that unchecking the box after a user's folders have been created will have no effect on those existing folders. The setting will be effective on newly created user folders. If you need this to be "retroactive" then you'll need to delete any existing user folders and allow Windows to recreate them (after you've unchecked the box).

[image]